# The default requested state parameter value length is not supported for my external authorization request in identity server 4 .Net Core

Tags: c#, identityserver4

```
1. Tried to customize the state parameter with the below code



options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (RedirectContext context) =>
                        {
                            //context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("CustomParameter", "Test");
                            //context.Properties.Items.Add(OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey, context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
                            //context.ProtocolMessage.State = context.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(context.Properties);
                            context.ProtocolMessage.State = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                            context.Response.Redirect(context.ProtocolMessage.CreateAuthenticationRequestUrl());
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
```

> Getting the below error after authenticated with external login screen.
>
> ```
> 2021-08-25 15:17:52.713 +00:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
>  ---> System.Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
>    at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.HandleRequestAsync()
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> ```
>
> context)
> at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
> middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

```
Q1: Is there any way to customize the state parameter value? Default generated value length is my only concern. 
Q2: Is it possible to set guid as status param value?

Please advise.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default context **Authentication properties** are encrypted by Protect method in **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** and then from the successful    authentication state, it will be decrypted by UnProtect method in **OnMessageReceived**. We have to in between mapping the data of the custom guid and the protected string later to Unprotect the Authentication properties.

```
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                        {
                            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (RedirectContext context) =>
                            {
                                //context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("CustomParameter", "Test");
                                context.Properties.Items.Add(OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey, context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri); ;
                                context.ProtocolMessage.State = CacheHelper.SetMemoryCache(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), context.Options.StateDataFormat.Protect(context.Properties));
                                context.Response.Redirect(context.ProtocolMessage.CreateAuthenticationRequestUrl());
                                context.HandleResponse();
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            },
                            OnMessageReceived = (MessageReceivedContext context) =>
                            {
                                context.ProtocolMessage.State = CacheHelper.GetMemoryCache(context.ProtocolMessage.State);
                                context.Properties = context.Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(context.ProtocolMessage.State);
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            },
                            OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = (AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context) =>
                            {
                                return Task.CompletedTask;
                            }
                        };
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver for our IdentityServer 6 clustered gateway environment.  Just tweaked your code to use redis and we were golden.  Thanks!